# Add Controls to Outlook 2003 Appointment Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, vsto, add-in, outlook-2003

I am developing an add-in for Outlook 2003. For this add-in, I need a few extra controls in the Appointment Window. However, I can't really wrap my head around the object model. When I developed add-ins for Outlook 2013, I had form regions in conjunction with the designer to work with. I tried searching Google but I only found articles about adding Toolbars and Controls to said Toolbars, but not in the Appointment (or any other) Window.

Can somebody give me a quick example or a link to an article?